# Spring-security-kerberos cross domain with trust

Tags: windows, active-directory, spring-security, kerberos, spring-security-kerberos

Is anyone aware if it's possible to provide cross-domain authentication with spring-security-kerberos assuming a trust is set up between the domains? I'm running a standard Java web application using spring-security and spring-security-kerberos on a Windows 2008 R2 server under Tomcat 7.

EDIT:

Running Java 1.6.0_30

My current krb5.ini

```
[libdefaults]
    default_realm = MY.DOMAIN
    dns_lookup_kdc = true
    dns_lookup_realm = true
[realms]
MY.DOMAIN = {
    default_domain = MY.DOMAIN
    kdc = MY.DOMAIN
}
```

Answer (score 0):

This is by default available in JGSS if you configure your krb5.ini correctly.

Comment: You wouldn't happen to have a link to some documentation on that?

Comment: Share your `krb5.ini`. What is your Java version?

Comment: added Krb5.ini to question.

Comment: Where is the cross-domain? You have only one domain in your conf.

Comment: Yes, that is my question. How would I configure this?

Comment: You need you put every participating realm in the `[realms]` and `[domain_realm]´ section.